# How to get only the numbers from a string array?

Tags: c#, regex

I've got an array of strings (`items`) which contain numbers and words - I'm pulling that from a Dictionary (`matches`) that has `int` and `string` values in it. I want to get an array or something I can loop through that just contains the numbers, sorted numerically, then show them in the console.

I can quite easily do this for individual strings by using regex, but when I have an array of strings I don't know how to do it.

Code below, see comments:

```
var matches = new Dictionary<int, string>();
matches.Add(1, "value1");
matches.Add(2, "value5");
matches.Add(3, "value2");
var items = matches.Values.ToArray();
Array.Sort(items, StringComparer.CurrentCulture);
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\D");
rgx.Replace(items, ""); //This doesn't work with arrays!
int[] numbers = Array.ConvertAll(items, s => int.Parse(s)); //This doesn't work because my strings still contain letters
foreach (int c in numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Number is {0}", c));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Desired output is:

```
Number is 1
Number is 5
Number is 2
```

Incase it's not obvious, those numbers come from `value1`, `value5` and `value2`.

Comment: When you can do it for a single string, you can also for arrays by iterating the array and doing it it per element.

Comment: Is there any built-in method to do that, rather than having to keep looping all the time? This seems like quite a trivial operation that should be do-able within a few lines of code, IMO

Comment: *which contain numbers and words* so which ones the number in `1 and 2`? `1` or `2` or `12`?

Comment: @Liam Numbers are in the `value1`, `value5` and `value2` strings

Comment: "This seems like quite a trivial operation that should be do-able within a few lines of code, IMO" Agree, so write a method tht does that for you. There´s no built-in way to apply a regex on a series of elements.

Comment: @HimBromBeere That's what I'm trying to do :) You ever got stuck on something and needed a bit of help though?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I don't really care but i'm curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using LINQ. The expression is pretty declarative and self-explaining:

```
// we're searching for digits, not removing non-digits as in your example
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+");

var results = matches.Values
    .Select(v => regex.Match(v))     // do regex on each item
    .Where(m => m.Success)           // select only those results where regex worked
    .Select(m => int.Parse(m.Value)) // convert to int
    .ToList();                       // convert the results to a list - if you want to sort it

// you wanted to sort the list, right?
results.Sort();

foreach (int number in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Number is {number}");
}
```

Comment: This is great, except it only seems to show the first number (1). To check, I printed `matches.Values` to the console and all three numbers were there. Any ideas?

Comment: @SyntaxError, this code works, [check here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oBKppL). Either you copied it not completely, or maybe you changed something.

Comment: Ah, i put `Console.ReadKey();` in the wrong place. WOrks now :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

doing it with `List<T>` instead of an Array will makes things easier!

```
var matches = new Dictionary<int, string>();
matches.Add(1, "value1");
matches.Add(2, "value5");
matches.Add(3, "value2");

var items = matches.Values.ToList();
items.Sort( StringComparer.CurrentCulture);
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\D");
var numbers = items.Select(i => int.Parse(rgx.Replace(i, "")));

foreach (int c in numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format($"Number is {c}"));
}
```

Comment: using a list instead of an array does not make any difference here, as OP is not adding elements once the collection is created. So a list does not provide any advantage in this case. In fact you can call `Select` on both.

Comment: you are right, it makes .ForEach() with I first considered and then left out

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using Regex :

```
            string[] input = { "Number is 1", "Number is 5", "Number is 2" };
            string pattern = @"\d+";

            int[] results = input.Select(x => Regex.Match(x, pattern)).Cast<Match>().Select(x => int.Parse(x.Value)).ToArray();
```